# Get new Date in Cloud Functions in specific time zone

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to get my local date time in Cloud Functions using `new Date()`, but the result is with offset + 3.
Is there any way to get the correct offset? Without convert, using  `new Date().getTimezoneOffset`

Comment: Can you provide
 the output?

Comment: What do you mean by "local" date time? Your computer timezone?

Comment: @aomerk 2019-11-25T11:18:56 , but the correct output should be 2019-11-25T08:18:56

Comment: @Freez my location , brazilian

Comment: @edilson14 get IP address from request and you can than use IP addresses location to get correct Date, if it is what you want. If you only want to output Brazilian look up `localeString` and how to use it

Comment: @aomerk when i use localeString the formate is different, and i want date in this formate `toISOString` :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A JavaScript Date object just represents a point in time for all people on the planet, without respect to timezone.  If you print the Date object, you will see a timezone, but that's just because the code that renders the date is using the timezone of the clock configured on the computer.  It's still the same point in time not matter what computer the date, or what timezone it's configured for.

If you want to format the date for people in a specific timezone, you will have to write some code for that.  A common library to help with that is [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/), using its [timezone plugin](https://momentjs.com/timezone/).

Comment: thanks , this worked for me but my reputation is under 15 so i can't up vote the response :/

Answer (score 6):

Cloud Functions run in GMT timezone, regardless of the environment's actual location. If you want the date/time in a specific timezone, you will have to convert it to that timezone yourself in your code.

Comment: can you provide any link/ document of the envirmonment's location , i didn't find anything about that on google

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method I created for Cloud Functions, hope it helps:

```
function datetimeLocal(timezone : number) : Date {
    const localdate = new Date(Date.parse(new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'UTC' })) + (timezone * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    return localdate;
 }
```

Then you can just call this function, passing the desired local timezone, eg.: datetimeLocal(-3) and you'll receive a new Date() object according to the timezone you need.

I repeat, for it to work, DONT NEED TO CHANGE THE STRINGS 'en-US' neither 'UTC'.