# How to remove timezone offset in cloud function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am creating a chart based on documents update, in each document, I also store update dateTime (current date with time). I can't store just date without time from the client side because I need the time later.

like this `1622221514407`

Then I want to get only the date without time from cloud function. But I am also getting the timezone offset, like added hour `05:30:00.000`. Which I don't want.

```
const todayDateTime = new Date(1622221514407);
const todayInMilliseconds = new Date(todayDateTime).setHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log(todayInMilliseconds);
```

the expected result is `1622140200000` but I am getting `1622160000000`
I checked this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58997898/10993985 but I don't want to format it. I just want to remove the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected result you are getting is correct as using a website to convert timestamps, you can see the timestamp of what it really is, and what it is to your local timezone
https://www.epochconverter.com/

You will notice that the timestamp is at 12:00:00 as this is midnight of that day.

All timestamps are universal and do not inherit timezones as they are built around the UTC but your OS will add its own timezone when rendering or printing the timestamp. Micromanaging this from an out-of-sync client can be problematic, so Firebase has introduced `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.servertimestamp` which triggers a hidden cloud function to store the current date.

In most cases, you only need to arrange the dates by order and on the client, simply ignore the hours. but if you need a true hourless timestamp, you will want to create a custom value that represents that time `year-month-day`. However, doing so means you may have trouble sorting the value but you can easily target a specific day in queries `.where("date", "==", "2021-07-21")`.

Utilizing both methods stored inside your document can yield the results you want without any complicated client timezone managment.